# Microsoft Bot Framework - Unable to set BotId in Emulator

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following line in my Web.config file under AppSettings

`<add key="BotId" value="[MY ID HERE]" />`

But the bot is not using this value, The bot framework emulator is showing the botid as "default-bot".

Comment: Emulator v3 or v4 Preview?

Comment: Emulator v3 shows a Botid like this "ab4bii416cl4" while v4 Preview shows a GUID as a BotId. So both dont show the correct BotId

Comment: So where do you have "botid as "default-bot"" ?

Comment: Its default-bot in v3 when not using Azure Bot channel registration, when using azure bot channel registration + ngrok its something like i mentioned above. Recently i have discovered BotId is the "Bot Handler" when I try to access the bot using direct line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v3 emulator does not provide the ability to set the botid.  'default-bot' is hard coded here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/1da9ab269d79723e3baefbd441a2eb24a1c3662e/packages/app/shared/src/types/serverSettingsTypes.ts#L120

```
export const settingsDefault: Settings = {
  framework: frameworkDefault,
  bots: [
    {
      'botId': 'default-bot',
      'botUrl': 'http://localhost:3978/api/messages',
      'msaAppId': '',
      'msaPassword': '',
      'locale': ''
    }
  ],
  windowState: windowStateDefault,
  users: usersDefault
};
```